# SSIS Job "Argument "ORARA********.xxxxxxx.COM" for option "connection" is not valid. The command line parameters are invalid. The step failed. " error

Tags: oracle, ssis, connections

My SSIS package is running fine in BIDS but when I tried to schedule the job it's showing:

> Argument "ORARACOCCUAT1.xxxxxxx.COM" for option "connection" is not valid.
>   The command line parameters are invalid.
>   The step failed.

I'm trying to move data from SQL Server to Oracle. I'm executing the package as well as scheduling the job in same server.

My command line is:

```
/FILE "C:\Users\..(snip)..\VERIFIERTERMCODE.dtsx"
/CONNECTION "10.226.211.222.KK.*";"Data Source=10.226.211.222;
User ID=*;Initial Catalog=KK;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;
Application Name=SSIS-VERIFIERTERMCODE-{6B1F6F56-1097-4F40-B681-217B3EB954C1}
10.226.211.222.KK.*;Auto Translate=False;\"" 
/CONNECTION "ORARACOCCUAT1.xxxxxxx.COM/LSSUATDB.*****";
"\"Data Source=ORARACOCCUAT1.xxxxxxx.COM/LSSUATDB;
User ID=*****;Password=****;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;\"" /X86
/CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E
```

*Steps I tried to fix this issue:*

1. As stated on [this](http://www.sqlserverbox.com/ssis-package-in-sql-server-agent-job-fails.html) site:

   > If your SQL Server is 64 bit
   >   In SQL Server JOB-->Properties-->Steps--->
   >   In the Execution Option Tab -- Check "Use 32 bit runtime"
   >   In the Data Sources Tab -- Uncheck the checkboxes of the connection managers if checked.
   >   Schedule the Job and run it.

...but that is not working for me and showing the same error.

2. As mentioned on [this](http://idoneitmyself.com/2013/11/18/argument-smtp-for-option-connection-is-not-valid-the-command-line-parameters-are-invalid/) site, removed hyphen and double quotes before Data source and after Provider but getting same error.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing the connection name(without space, dot,comma) of both source and destination in Package itself and I tried to run the job manually by clicking Start Job at Step and it worked fine :)